# How to get child class objects from array list?

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble getting the earlier class objects of an array list in the 'onPostExecute' method of my asynch class.  To simplify things for this post, I'm just trying to set the text of the 'name' to my textview in my onPostExecute method like so.

> myTextView.setText(VideoDetail_List.get(0).getVideoName());

However the problem is that the String that is returning is the last instance of the videoname object in the string array, instead of the first instance of the video name, which should be the child class object of the VideoDetail_List at the 0 index.

> `AsyncTask Class`

```
        final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
        final JSONArray videoData = obj.getJSONArray("data");

        final int n = videoData.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            final JSONObject video = videoData.getJSONObject(i);
            videoDetail.setVideoName(video.getString("name"));
            videoDetail.setVideoDuration(video.getString("duration"));
            final JSONObject videoPictures = video.getJSONObject("pictures");
            final JSONArray videoPictureSizes = videoPictures.getJSONArray("sizes");
            final JSONObject videoPictureLink = videoPictureSizes.getJSONObject(1);

            videoDetail.setPictureLink(videoPictureLink.getString("link"));
            //pictureLink.add(videoPictureLink.getString("link"));

            final JSONArray videoURLTypes = video.getJSONArray("download");
            final JSONObject videoURLLink = videoURLTypes.getJSONObject(0);

            videoDetail.setVideoLink(videoURLLink.getString("link"));
            //videoLink.add(videoURLLink.getString("link"));
            VideoDetail_List.add(i,videoDetail);

        }

        return VideoDetail_List;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<VideoDetail> VideoDetail_List) {


    System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + VideoDetail_List);

    final TextView myTextView = new TextView(mContext);

    myTextView.setText(VideoDetail_List.get(0).getVideoName());



    mLayout.addView(myTextView);

    myTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String sText = myTextView.getText().toString();
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, sText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, sText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();



        }
    });


}
```

> VideoDetail Class

```
public class VideoDetail {
    private String videoName;
    private String videoDuration;
    private String pictureLink;
    private String videoLink;




    public String getVideoName() {
        return this.videoName;
    }

    public void setVideoName(String videoName) {
        this.videoName = videoName;
    }

    public String getVideoDuration() {
        return videoDuration;
    }

    public void setVideoDuration(String videoDuration) {
        this.videoDuration = videoDuration;
    }

    public String getPictureLink() {
        return pictureLink;
    }

    public void setPictureLink(String pictureLink) {
        this.pictureLink = pictureLink;
    }

    public void setVideoLink(String videoLink){
        this.videoLink = videoLink;
    }
    public String getVideoLink() {
        return videoLink;
    }


}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However the problem is that the String that is returning is the last
>   instance of the videoname object in the string array

That's because you are overriding the content of the only instance of VideoDetails at every iteration of your for loop. You should instantiate it at every iteration

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     videoDetail = new VideoDetail();
```